# How to port a NetBeans project on a different computer?

Tags: netbeans, relative-path, porting

I developed a C++ project with NetBeans on Linux, and it is working fine.
Now I would like to rebuild it on a different computer, with a different directory structure.

However, the path of every file stored in the IDE is still the one of the previous computer, so the files seem not to exist under the IDE point of view.

In NetBeans I tried to do what follows both on the first computer, before tar, and on the target machine:

1. Project Properties/General/Source folder set relative to the project.
2. Tools/Options/C/C++/Project Options/File Path Mode/Always Relative

This did not fix the problem. On the target machine I still have absolute paths.
I could create a new project from scratch, but I would avoid doing that.

Any idea?

Thank you!

*Platform:*
Linux - OpenSuse 10.1/11.4
Netbeans 7.1

Comment: I have not used NB for C++ in a while but in the files created by NB there might be files marked as private, don't copy those to the target machine.

Comment: @madth3, I just tried to exclude the "private" directory in "nbproject/", but with no success.